# Question about 'reading' probability.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a basic question in probability:

Does `P(A|E,B)` mean that probability of `A` given, `E` and `B`, both?  And what about `P(B,A|E)`?  Are they the same?

I am asking because my professor used the second notation once (and then for some reasons just dropped `B` in the next step).

Edit:  Also do we read a comma (`,` as in the case above) as `and`, meaning that `E` and `B` both happen?  Is it true always?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Feel free to downvote, but then please also guide me!

Comment: Nevermind, thank you!

Comment: Please feel free to close this question for any reason whatsoever.  I won't delete this, just to let new users know that it is pretty obvious to have such questions (although they might not easily get an answer).  Thanks.